# How are the results of intermediate steps in an arithmetic expression stored when all terms in the expression are uint8_t?

Tags: c, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

The code:

```
int main(void) {
    uint8_t x = 3;
    uint8_t y = 4;
    uint8_t z = 5;

    uint8_t a = (x - y) / z;
    uint8_t b = x - y;
    printf("a is %d\n", a);
    printf("b is %d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

had the following output:

```
a is 0
b is 255
```

I would expect that `(3 - 4) / 5` would result in an overflow as `(3 - 4)` as a `uint8_t` is 255.  When an intermediate step involving unsigned integers results in a negative number, why doesn't it overflow? In what format is the result for `(3 - 4)` stored before the next step `/ 5` happens?

Comment: `%d` is not a correct format specifier for `uint8_t`. And yes, arithmetic is performed with the operands promoted to `int`. So `(x-y)` will actually ecaluate to `-1` and will have the type `int`.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? `gcc -Wall` gives as output `a is 0
b is 255`. And for those values I could maybe cobble an explanation together.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `uint8_t` gets promoted to `int` when you use it in a `printf`, so `"%d"` should be the correct specifier.

Comment: @mch I was not sure about that. I recall there is a special promotion rule for variadic functions

Comment: Actually here is the explanation for 255 and 0:  3-4 = -1, which in complement 2 representation is 255. If you divide -1 by something, the result is float, which implies capability to represent negatives. If you divide it by someting higher than 1, the result is between 0 and -1. If you force that into an integer, it gets rounded to 0.

Comment: If you are using gcc then which one and how, i.e. which switches and which platform. Assuming that it is used on a .c file. And can you give the complete MCVE?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I'm using gcc.

Comment: @Yunnosch There are clear rules about it, no need to improvise. The operands are promoted to `int` when performing arithmetic. That's it.

Comment: I still have problems imagining any gcc to represent (3-4) as 253.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are right, no need for the detour via float.

Comment: And yes, 253 seems strange. I would bet on typo / discrepancy between the actual and presented code.

Comment: Only way to make 253 which I can think of is complement one representation of (3-5). But that would be a strange gcc and assuming a mistake by OP. That's why I would love to see the MCVE.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Yunnosch - What is wrong with this question?

Comment: I changed the title, as the behaviour is different for unsigned integer types smaller than `unsigned int`, which is what you are asking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use a much simpler example to see what's really going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t x = 3;
    uint8_t y = 4;

    int a = (x - y);
    printf("a is %d\n", a);    // a is -1
    return 0;
}
```

<sub>(*Live example: http://ideone.com/C3SlIn*)</sub>

What you're seeing there is the result of the *integer promotions* that are performed on the operands to `-` as part of the *usual arithmetic conversions*.<sup>1</sup>  Relevant parts of the definition of integer promotions from the (C99) standard:

> **[6.3.1.1]** If an `int` can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`.

An `int` can indeed represent all values of a `uint8_t`, so that subtraction is really equivalent to:

```
int a = (int)x - (int)y;
```

In other words, there is no overflow.

---

<sub>1. But to preempt one common confusion, this behaviour is **inherent** to how `-` works; it's not because we're assigning to an `int` here.</sub>